# Develop/Run Dapps with Node.js

Tags: nodejs

I read in the manual that programmers can use common languages to program Dapps.

Questions:

- So I could program a Dapp without Solidity just with `JS`, `node.js`, `HTML`, `CSS`, and `HTML`. Or do I still need Solidity?
- How will users run the app? Don't they require `node.js` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the Front end from the backend :

**Backend**
to write a Dapp you need to write a contract which is commonly written in solidity (or Serpent).

**Frontend**
in the front end you could use the Css, HTML .. to build the interface, and Web3.js framwork to interact with the contract.

in order to run the dapp you need first to deploy the contract in the ethereum network (you could setup your private chain) and you need a browser to run you application like mist or there is a chrome extension(MetaMask) to browse Dapps.

here you will find a sample i have developed using solidity and web3.js

https://github.com/bellaj/Ballot-Dapp

Comment: Ok, so I can choose in the front end what I want but the backend is solidity?

Comment: I basically would avoid to get to deep into new languages, if possible.

Comment: you are free to use what you want the important is web3.js and solidity to write your contract.

Comment: I still don't get it, how can users use anything which is not standard in the browser if I don't host the site (&install the tools)?

Comment: the dapp is not a standard webapp it is a different thing even if they share same frontend bases. because in dapp we send transactions to the ethereum network not to webserver so the browser should have this ability

Comment: think of it like if you need to browse an app in the Darknet

Comment: so we can't use traditional browsers